# My path variable looks strange

Tags: bash

In console when I type:

```
echo $PATH
```

I see

```
/Users/jeffrey.wan/.rbenv/shims:/Users/jeffrey.wan/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

So the absolute paths that are looked up whenever a user types in a command at the command line that is not built into the shell are:

/Users/jeffrey.wan/.rbenv/shims
/Users/jeffrey.wan/.rbenv/shims
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin

How did this happen that there is some doubling? Is this a problem?

What should I do to eliminate that? I recently moved some stuff in my bash_profile that I didn't understand.

Also, what are rbenv shims?

Comment: If `/Users/jeffrey.wan/` is not you, it's a bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate paths in `PATH` are generally not a problem. It might result in these paths being searched multiple times by code searching for executables in directories specified in the `PATH` environment variable, which might result in slightly decreased performance.

Most likely the changes to your profile are the cause of this. Check your profile settings (e.g. in `.bash_profile` and other scripts) which change `PATH`.

The rbenv shims are probably related to [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) or Ruby.

Comment: What can I write in my bash profile that would eliminate the doubling? got a solution so I can give you credit?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you changed in those files. Its hard to give a good answer. An easy workaround might be to append `export PATH="WHATEVER:YOU:WANT:IT:TO:BE"` to one or both of these files.

Comment: It's *really* not worth worrying about. Whatever minimal performance hit occurs by looking in an extra directory only occurs the *first* time you run a command in a session. `bash` caches successful lookups.

Comment: The doubling probably happened when you installed the same thing (`rbenv`?) twice, and it carelessly didn't check if it had already added stuff to your `.bashrc` or whatever. Find and remove the duplicated lines.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to handle this is to not rely on some BOFH to set your PATH. It's *your* PATH, right? So you set it yourself in whatever startup file your shell reads at login time (usually `.profile` or `.bashrc` for bash). There's a nifty tool named `getconf` that tells the default system PATH. Use it as follows:

```
PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
...
```

I recommend a list of single lines, adding one directory each, so you can easily rearrange them, should the need arise.